# Export data from continuous form to Excel w/o header fields

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, export-to-excel

I have a continuous form, where the form header contains filter options, and the details section contains the data.

I want to be able to export this to excel. the basic VBA code works

```
DoCmd.OutputTo
```

but when I export to Excel, it also includes the form header controls for each row.

Is there any way to set a property that will exclude the form header from being included in the export? Basically, only export the form details section?

I prefer not to use a query

I have 6 unbound txt boxes in the header:
- artnr
- Artnr supplier
- description
- article status
- supplier name
- supplier number
and i have a search button, wich holds this code:

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()

    Dim strWhere As String
    Dim lngLen As Long

'artikel zoeken
    If Not IsNull(Me.txtSearchArtnr) Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "([Material] Like ""*" & Me.txtSearchArtnr & "*"") AND "
    End If

'artnr leverancier zoeken
    If Not IsNull(Me.txtSearchSupplArt) Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "([LiefMat] Like ""*" & Me.txtSearchSupplArt & "*"") AND "
    End If

'trefwoord zoeken
    If Not IsNull(Me.txtSearchKeyword) Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "([Materialkurztext] Like ""*" & Me.txtSearchKeyword & "*"") AND "
    End If

'artikelstatus zoeken
    If Not IsNull(Me.txtSearchStatus) Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "([Status] Like ""*" & Me.txtSearchStatus & "*"") AND "
    End If

'leverancier naam zoeken
    If Not IsNull(Me.txtSearchSupplName) Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "([Name 1] Like ""*" & Me.txtSearchSupplName & "*"") AND "
    End If

'leverancier nummer zoeken
    If Not IsNull(Me.txtSearchSupplNumber) Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "([Lieferant] Like ""*" & Me.txtSearchSupplNumber & "*"") AND "
    End If

'***********************************************************************
'Chop off the trailing " AND ", and use the string as the form's Filter.
'***********************************************************************
'See if the string has more than 5 characters (a trailng " AND ") to remove.

    lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
    If lngLen <= 0 Then     'Nah: there was nothing in the string.
        MsgBox "Geen criteria gevonden", vbInformation, "Geen resultaten."

    Else                    'Yep: there is something there, so remove the " AND " at the end.
        strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)

        'Apply the string as the form's Filter.
        Me.Filter = strWhere
        Me.FilterOn = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you put the filter on a query and export the results of the query?  That sounds like a much easier way to do it.

Comment: From what I have read, you can't exclude the header row for an export - only on import. One option is to do the export, then run VBA code to open the Excel file and delete row 1.

Comment: it's not the header row I want to exclude.
in the header of my access form I created unbound text boxes to search in all records. e.g. people can search for a keyword in an article description. when they have found what they need, which could be multiple records, they need to be able to export those results to excel. but when I do this cia the docmd.output to, the unbound text boxes each also become a column in my excel file.

Comment: Can you put the unbound textboxes in the form footer instead of the header?

Comment: Here is something neat that I just found and tested... http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=149974

Comment: @Mike No I can't. Because it would be unlogical for my colleagues. and the header holds my company logo so I want to keep everything there. and since my colleagues are very bad with computers, it needs to look the same as our ERP program so that they don't need much to figure out how it works.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn I will have a look at the link and have a go at it. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the sollution here:

[Exporting selected records to excel - hiding certain columns](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=233101)

```
DoCmd.Echo False

Me.Field1.Visible = False
Me.Field2.Visible = False
Me.Field3.Visible = False

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdOutputToExcel

Me.Field1.Visible = True
Me.Field2.Visible = True
Me.Field3.Visible = True

DoCmd.Echo True

End Sub
```

it's simple and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

you write, that users can set filters, so you must have programmed something like
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT ... FROM table WHERE --here the criterias--"
Me.Requery
so you could take the SQL-Statement and use it for export, you first have to create a query

```
    Dim sSQL As String
    Dim qd As QueryDef

    Set qd = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("tmp_Query")
    qd.SQL = "Select * from T_Personal"

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "tmp_Query", "yourfile", True

    CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete qd.Name
```

wrap it into a function, so you can fire it anywhere and pass the sql and filename ...

HTH

Comment: I've added some more info to my question. I hope that will help in search for an answer :)

Comment: Hi Isabel
well, as you use the filter functionality, you can use the prepared where-statement and combine it with the recordsource of the form:
sSQL = Me.RecordSource & " WHERE " & strWhere
and take my sample code above to create the query and then export to excel

Comment: thanks! but where do I put the SQL statement you mention? and the code you gave me, can I put this in my form's button on click event? basically I would appreciate if you could tell me the steps that I need to take :)

Comment: Hi Isabel - well, you can add it at the end of your existing filter-code, but i assume that you don't want to export each time the user changes the filter. So i would see a button on the form to fire the export. There you can put the code. But then you have to combine the SQL like this: sSQL = Me.RecordSource & " WHERE " & Me.Filter (as you definded the strWhere within the button for filter) - or you define the strWhere on Form level in the declaration section

Comment: so I replace the qd.SQL line in your code with sSQL = Me.RecordSource & " WHERE " & Me.Filter?